# ASP.NET web parts - not stored in a cookie

Tags: asp.net, web-parts, personalization

Recently I was reading the [MCTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Certified_Professional#Technology_Series_.28MCTS.29) ASP.NET 3.5 exam preparation book. I finished the lesson about web parts. The author said that user personalization is stored in a database and tracked by a cookie in a web browser.

I checked the database - it's there.

It seems however that the personalization information has noting to do with a cookie. It is recognized across multiple browsers. I even tried deleting all cookies and the webparts state are the same across browsers.

Do you have any idea WHY is that and HOW does it work without a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

This may shed some light on how, [Web Parts Personalization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z36h8be9.aspx), you basically setup [SQLServer as the provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58sw37f7.aspx) to manage the personalization data